# Multiple .py files into .exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have multiple `.py` files in one folder and I want them to work together in one `.exe`.

The structure is really simple.

I have one `GUI.py`, one `Workfile.py` and one `Config.py`.

The `GUI.py` should kick off the `Workfile.py` in a new process.

Executed in Visual Studio it works perfectly fine.

But when I create an `.exe` of the `GUI.py` with `pyinstaller --onefile GUI.py`, it is not able to kick off the `Workfile.py` when executed.

How can I create one `.exe` that works with all three files together?

---

This is the .spec file i get when running pyinstaller --onefile Interface.py  (renamed my GUI.py)

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Interface.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\johannes\\Desktop\\Python'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Interface',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Comment: If you can share your .spec file, and some of the code, it would be easier to try and figure out the issue.

Comment: I postet a new answer with the .spec file. Do i need a maybe need something like a main file that connects all three .py files?

Comment: When you say the `GUI.py` is *not able to kick off* `Workfile.py` - what exactly happens? Do you get any specific errors?

Comment: How are you kicking off the other files? `Popen([sys.executable...`? `import myfile`?